# Check validation on nested array dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, nested

```
{
     "name" : "parent_node",
     "children: 
[
    {
        "name" : "child-1",
        "children:
    [
            {
                "name" : "subchild-1",
               //unlimited childrens

            }
     ]  
    }

    ]
}


               ------------------------------------------

$rules = ([
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'children.*.name' => 'required|string'
         ]);
```

1. I want to check validation dynamically on dynamic nested array
2. Instead of using 'children.*.name
3. Validation should check nested array itself because i didn't bound
   nested array at any level, so there are infinite levels
4. You can see the image
   'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PAZC_TQQpwSEsY-ecUjh4lKoNcpKoOj9/view?usp=sharing'

Comment: Manually iterate until there is node.children

Comment: how can i iterate? i tried it many times

Comment: I mean by overriding the validation process. But the simplest thing to do would be to check the rules manually on form submit

Comment: i am not using form validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible to validate recursively using Laravel validation. you will have to do it manually for example

```
$children = $request->children;
if(!is_null($children[0]) {
    $children[0]->name;

    if(!is_null($children[0]->children[0]) {
        $children[0]->children[0]->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this to store nested array in DB its working but I am trying to use it on validation rules but i can't.
 
$node[] = $request->all();
    
        //loop for each nested array
    
        foreach($node as $node){
    
            //create every nested array
                Node::create($node);
            }

Comment: yes @TheKayi'sKitchen, you can loop your result like that but probably have to change variable name a bit. foreach($nodes as $node)

Comment: validation rule does not support recursive validation like this afaik.

Comment: $rules[] = ([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'children' => 'array',
            'children.*.name' => 'required|string',
                   ]);
i tried it like this but it only validates first child only

Comment: @TheKayi'sKitchen yes, that's what i was saying